# Test app performance by making it lag

Tags: performance, lag

Is there a way or an application to test performance by making the app execute slower? I want to be sure that my app will perform well on older hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding stalls in SW won't necessarily imitate any older HW, it would just show you how the stalled code behaves on the new HW  (and if the stalls aren't properly serializing - they may actually get avoided altogether).

If you just want to see how the code behaves without some specific ISA features you can disable them on compilation, or even compile to an older architecture. That won't make your CPU run any slower of course, but it won't be able to use for example AVX/SSE vectors (in x86 for e.g.), or other dedicated instructions.

If you want on old system+OS configuration you can use emulation - for e.g. DosBox

If you want an even higher level of realism, you can find a HW simulator that models that HW, and run on that (assuming you can cross-compile your code to run on it).

And of course, if you want an even more realistic experiment, and willing to go the extra mile, just get a specimen of that old HW, wipe the dust off, and build and run on it :)