# How to limit PC performance to test software

Tags: performance

I am developing a .NET application, and have the luxury of doing this on a fairly powerful desktop PC.  I want to ensure it runs okay on PCs with much lower spec, but I don't have spare machines kicking around and can't really afford to buy them.  Is there any way to simulate a lower-spec PC on my current PC, to get a feel for how the software might run?

Any help or advice would be very much appreciated.

<sub>*My PC is Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit with 8-core Intel i7 and 16GB RAM.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You could [install VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/nl/products/workstation/) and install any OS you want, with any hardware specs you want, provided that they don't exceed your current working hardware of course.

Keep in mind that VMWare is just a virtualization layer. It emulates an OS but you are still running your code on the same i7.

Comment: vmware could emulate a lesser OS, devices, limit cores, memory and other arch specs, but you'll still be running a powerful i7 core (although with the penalty of a virtualization layer). But you're right in that it's the best he can do.

Comment: Agreed now, +1. See also related question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598082/test-app-performance-by-making-it-lag

Comment: That sounds good, except... wouldn't I need another WindowsXX licence to install into the VMWare virtual machine?  In my experience, it'd be cheaper to buy a second hand laptop than try to get another Windows licence.

Comment: @Patrick Yes, you need a windows license to install it, but I think you can install some versions of windows as trial licenses.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asp.net/mobile/device-simulators  Here is an example of several Visual Studio plug-ins that emulate devices.  You can also install Windows 8 and run hyper-v.  It's great for this kind of thing.